# Data corrupted: When resending Paypal Ipn post

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn

The first time I am getting the Ipn call from Paypal,the post data that come with it is fine and I managed to process it, but when I resending the Ipn from the Ipn history from my Paypal account I am getting the following post data

```
????&cmd=_notify-validate


            string strLive = _varsConfig._payPalDomain + "cgi-bin/webscr";
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strLive);


        //Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
        string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
        strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;            

        //for proxy
        //WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://url:port#"));
        //req.Proxy = proxy;

        //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();
        StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        streamIn.Close();
```

Comment: Can you add more information about how you send PayPal lpn?

Comment: What do you mean , from my paypal account in the Ipn history i am just checking up the transaction that i want to resend and press resend

Comment: how are you doing it in code?